# Tensor computation and testing

Tags: computer-science, tensor-products, tensors

I am currently testing several tensor-libraries in C++ for speed and performance. My tests are comprised of increasing size, dimensionality and complexity of the computation. But i would also like some "real-world" examples, to give perspective, on how well, they would work for "practicing" physicists. 
Could you maybe give some examples of some Tensor-calculations and equations, that i could use?

EDIT: Obviously, anything chemists or mathematicians have to do is also fine.

Comment: Are you aware that there is a physics.stackexchange?

Comment: Yes, obviously, but if i am not mistaken, then mathematicians also use tensors, do they not?

Comment: Why is that obvious? The best source for real world examples to give perspective on how tensors would work for practicing physicists would probably be practicing physicists.

Comment: To evaluate libraries against each other, you would really need to have specific use-cases in mind, so I agree with the above commenter and recommend you ask in multiple places, such as the physics stackexchange. As someone working in algebra, the tensor products I generally work with are far too large (in dimension) to do anything useful with directly on a computer.